# How to make a simple POST function with flask?

Tags: python, flask, post

I made a local service to learn flask and trying to write some get/post functions. I have no problem with GET but POST just confused me a bit. What I want to do is when some user send his name as POST request service will return as "Hello name". I made some research but everything I saw was so complicated and full of json. I do not want to use json because I just send a string and return a string. Can you guys just help me with that and tell me how can I test that post request on curl? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I tried to write my data in json format as

```
data = { "name" : " "}
```

and tried to post like

```
@app.route("/f",methods=['POST'])
def f():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    myName = request_data['name']
    return (str(myName))
```

but did not work.

Comment: Could you please show, what you've tried already and point to a specific problem you've encountered?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Ah I tho what I tried was so amateur and the problem is actually I do not know how to do it. I tried to make it in json format as `data = { "name" : " "}` and `@app.route("/f",methods=['POST'])

def f():

    request_data = request.get_json()

    myName = request_data['name']
    

    return (str(myName))`

Comment: You can edit your post and add the code to it. It's hard to read it in the comment.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych yes, did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Install Flask

```
pip3 install flash
```

Step 2: Create a file `app.py` with:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def data():
    rq = request.form

    return 'Hello ' + rq.get('name', 'No name')
```

Step 3: Start Flask

```
export FLASK_APP=hello.py
flask run
```

Step 4: Call the app with cURL

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/ -d "name=Bob"
```

->

```
Hello Bob
```

---

Json alternative:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def data():
    rq = request.get_json()

    return 'Hello ' + rq.get('name', 'No name')
```

Then the cURL would be:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/ \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"name": "Bob"}'
```

->

```
Hello Bob
```

Comment: These are from HTML form and JSON. OP asks about raw strings

Comment: I rephrased with the most simple explanation possible. He wants to send a POST of a string and display that string

Comment: As suggested I will use json format and it works fine, thank you for your kind answer!